# How to do data validation in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3, alert

I made a crud using codeigniter 3, where there are two tables that are connected to each other using a primary key and a foreign key, how do I validate so that the primary key cannot be deleted if there is still a foreign key connected by displaying alerts, and the primary key can be deleted if there is no data connected.

[Alert display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq73G.png)

Controllers

```
public function delete($id) {
$data['kelas'] = $this->Kelas_model->delete_data($id);
$this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 
  '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    Data Deleted Successfully!
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
  </div>');
redirect('kelas'); }
```

Models

```
public function delete_data($id_kelas) {
$this->db->where('id_kelas', $id_kelas);
return $this->db->delete('kelas'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to avoid deleting rows instead you can hide/show them on the basis of their status for example you can create a column "is_deleted" by default = 0 and when user wants to delete the row you can update is_deleted = 1 and when fetching data you can use where clause as where is_deleted = 0

hope I make sense to you.